# Understanding python multiprocessing: does code wait for all process to finish

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a piece of code which looks as following:

```
Data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def Fn2(obj):
  return 2*obj

p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
valueList = p.map(Fn2, Data) #---question Line 1
valueList = 2*valueList  #--question Line 2
```

At `Line 1` the processors are returning values which gets stored in `valueList`. I have 8 cores on my computer. Initially job gets assigned to all cores. When let's say out of 8 cores, 5 cores free up. Do the rest of cores jump to `Line 2` or wait for all cores to finish the job and fill up the `valueList` and then proceed to `Line 2`.

How do I test your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the rest of cores jump to Line 2

No.

> How do I test your answer?

When in doubt about code running in parallel, add `sleep`s. When in doubt about code in general, add `print`s.

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

from multiprocess import Pool

Data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def Fn2(obj):
    print(obj)
    sleep(2)
    return 2 * obj

p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
valueList = p.map(Fn2, Data)  # ---question Line 1
print(valueList)
valueList = 2 * valueList  # --question Line 2
```

This gives the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

And based on the timing it should be clear what's going on. Try tweaking the pool size to 3 or something to experiment further.